# CSL Style Formatting Questions

Tags: citations, mendeley, csl

I have two questions I was hoping the community could help me with. I'm specially using CSL in Mendeley with the Microsoft Word plugin.

1. Do you know how to control the spacing/tab between the number of the citation and the author names? I want this to be a space, but in the style I have it is a tab. I an unable to find this option! Please see screenshot #1.

[example of the space between citation number and citation text in the bibliograpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4kyJ.png)

2. Is there a way I can control formatting of the bibliography using a word style? For example, I want it to remove the hanging indent and match the font/size of the rest of my document. See Screenshot #2.

[example of the difference in formatting between the bibliography list and the remainder of the text of the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5B7K.png)

Many thanks for taking the time to answer these questions!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can address by removing the `second-field-align="flush"` from the `bibliography` line of the style and instead just setting a `suffix=" "` on `<text variable="citation-number"/>`. However that will mean (by definition of what a space does) that subsequent lines will not start flush with the text, but will begin at the beginning of the line (though it sounds like that may be what you want anyway?). If you just want the tab to be *shorter* you can fix that in Word.
2. No, Mendely and CSL do not allow you to automatically address the Word style you're using. I believe the bibliography will get inserted with its own Word style, though, so you can modify that once and have the changes stick.

Comment: Hey, this is great! Exactly what I was looking. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Great! Stack Overflow norms are to just upvote & accept my answer rather than write a thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/tour